# grub terminal mode crashes laptop

Tags: linux, grub, crash

Since today my work laptop (Dell Precision 7560 + LUKS + archlinux) refuses to boot. Here's what happens:

1. I'm prompted to enter my passphrase
2. the encrypted slot opens and the laptop powers off
3. the laptop boots into BIOS

Here's what I tried so far:

1. enter the passphrase wrong on purpose to get into rescue mode
2. cryptomount the respective partition (works)
3. and then:

   - try to boot normally -> crashes
   - try to find the usb with a live disk -> no luck
   - look for some boot logs -> no luck, don't know where they are or if there are any

What could even cause the whole laptop to simply power down with no error whatsoever?

The BIOS system logs "ASF2 force off" and that's all... (btw, all hardware checks passed, so of course it's "linux' fault")

Answer (score 0):

https://endeavouros.com/news/full-transparency-on-the-grub-issue/

apparently the latest update broke my bootloader.